# How to import a module without exports?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Problem happens when I want to use a plugin krpano(https://krpano.com/) in my project.

It can be imported through a `script` tag according to the official tutorial. Like

`<script src="krpano.js"></script>`

And then the function `embedpano` will be added to the `window` object. Call it like

`embedpano({swf:"krpano.swf", xml:"pano.xml", target:"pano"});`

But I want to wrap it up, so I try to import it directly in my wrapper file. like

`import "@/libs/krpano.js";`

When I call the function it throws an error `'embedpano' is not defined.`

I add a line `window.embedpano = embedpano;` to the end of `krpano.js` and it works.
But I don't want to modify plugin files every time when I use modules without exports.

Is there more elegant way to import such modules without exports? Just like import it through `script` tags?

Comment: If the library is not written as an ES6 module, you shouldn't `import` it.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your answer. I solved it with using ```require``` instead of ```import```.

Comment: What is `require`? Are you using a library?

Comment: @Bergi Yes. I post my solution as my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I use `require` instead of `import`. Like

`let lib = require("@/libs/krpano.js");`

Then the object `lib` will includes the functions `embedpano` and `removepano` whitch are inside the module without exports.